# ¿Como realizar INNER JOIN con 3 tablas utilizando MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una duda con una consulta **INNER JOIN**, en mi Base de datos tengo 3 tablas que son las siguientes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Su estructura es la siguiente la **tabla nivel_educativo** ser relaciona con la tabla **becario** y la tabla becario se relaciona con la tabla **calificaciones**.
El problema es que al querer obtener información de las tres tablas mediante PHP no me devuelve ningún valor, el código es el siguiente:

```
$sql_calificaciones = "SELECT becarios.*, nivel_educativo.nivel, calificaciones.calificacion
                            FROM calificaciones
                                INNER JOIN becarios
                                    ON calificaciones.id_becario = becarios.id_becario
                            FROM becarios
                                INNER JOIN nivel_educativo
                                    ON becarios.id_nivel = nivel_educativo.id_nivel";

$registros = obtenerRegistro($sql_calificaciones, $conecta);

if ($registros !== false) 
{
    echo var_dump($registros);
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: No se ve ningún campo(id_nivel) en la tabla becarios(imagen) que relacione con la tabla nivel_educativo , mas sin embargo en tu query lo pones

Comment: como dijo @Ricardo, no se ve ningún cambo id_nivel en la tabla becarios, y tienes 2 FROM en la consulta que probablemente te tiren un error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La forma correcta para ejecutar el JOIN sería de la siguiente manera:

```sql
SELECT becarios.*, nivel_educativo.nivel, calificaciones.calificacion
    FROM calificaciones
       INNER JOIN becarios ON calificaciones.id_becario = becarios.id_becario
       INNER JOIN nivel_educativo ON becarios.id_nivel = nivel_educativo.id_nivel
```

Los inner join se van concatenando, becarios hace join sobre calificaciones y nivel_educativo sobre becarios y calificaciones, y asi podrías hacerlo consecutivamente con mas tablas.

Espero te sea útil.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces joins solo debes poner el primer FROM. El segundo estaba de mas.
Prueba asi:

```
$sql_calificaciones = "SELECT becarios.*, nivel_educativo.nivel, calificaciones.calificacion
                            FROM calificaciones
                                INNER JOIN becarios
                                    ON calificaciones.id_becario = becarios.id_becario
                                INNER JOIN nivel_educativo
                                    ON becarios.id_nivel = nivel_educativo.id_nivel";

$registros = obtenerRegistro($sql_calificaciones, $conecta);

if ($registros !== false) 
{
    echo var_dump($registros);
}
```

Para aprender a usar correctamente los joins puedes hacer click [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)